# Writing HTML To A File

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a table that is partially populated by the user and I would like to save the resulting HTML to a file.  The code I am using is:

```
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
string myPageHTML = null;
byte[] requestHTML;
string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(currentPageUrl);
myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML);
string outputFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + "outputFile.html";
FileStream fs = File.Open(outputFileLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.WriteLine(myPageHTML);
}
```

The problem seems to be that this code sends a new request for the page so that I end up getting the initial page view and not the HTML resulting from user input.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: have you call sw.Flush() and sw.Close method ? also fs.flush and fs.Close ?

Comment: I thought "using" took care of those things.  Anyway I tried it but the result is the same.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua `sw.Flush/Close` isn't needed as it's in a `using()` block.

Comment: @BaliC you are right, but fs is outside from using block.

Answer (score 2):

I would put your method in the Render Method and change it to the following

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
 sw = new StringWriter();
 htmltw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
 base.Render(htmltw);
 StringBuilder html = sw.GetStringBuilder();

 string outputFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + "outputFile.html";
 FileStream fs = File.Open(outputFileLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
 {
  sw.WriteLine(html);

 }
 writer.Write(sOut);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am bit new at this -- could you tell me how to add to the event?

Comment: My mistake, override the Render method with the above

Comment: I am trying `protected override void Render(object sender, EventArgs e)` but my editor is complaining there is "no suitable method found to override".

Comment: protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I rebuilt the web page and the error message went away.

Comment: Have changed the code, shoudl do what you need now. Sorry, i dont have VS to hand

Comment: There must be something basic I am not understanding.  Running this code, with `writer.Write(sOut)` commented out because it is not defined, gives me this error message: "XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:1746/WebApp/NetworkOperationsReport.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:"